# Linux ld Error When Trying To Compile A C++ Project On Visual Studio Code With External Library

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, ld

I'm having some hard time trying to understand why my C++ project won't compile due to an error on ld, which says:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by libs/idkit/libc++_shared.so,
> not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

My scenario:
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit
Visual Studio Code

I've already tried a lot of workaround but can't get it to work.

My *tasks.json* is configured like this:

```
{
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "cppbuild",
                "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
                "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
                "args": [
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "-Llibs/idkit",
    
                "-lc++_shared",
                    "-Lusr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                    "-lc"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code exactly have you tried and what were the results.
More details on what you tried and its results might help others in locating the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to run a method of that lib (idkit). But when I try, the error about libc++shared.so occurs. This lib was created to run on a Android device. I don't know if this error happens because I'm trying to run on a Linux and not a Android device. I don't think so, because the "libc++_shared.so" exists on the system folders. This might be some file access error. But I don't get it to work.